# Bind radio button dynamically xamarin and clicked event

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi I am working on radio button in popup. Instead of Picker i want to bind Radio button with list.

I tried with selection view but it is not working . I am not getting click event of same.

Comment: Showing us some code would help.

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved. I have bind from class and passed list to itemsource